# .NET C# IIS A solicitação foi anulada: Não foi possível criar um canal seguro para SSL/TLS

Tags: c#, web-service, nfe

Srs,

Estou tentando me comunicar com o servidor da receita/SEFAZ usando um certificado A1 através de uma aplicação MVC5 C# em um servidor IIS 8, no pool com a identidade do meu usuário. O certificado está instalado e já realizei os devidos testes conectando na receita diretamente pelo Browser. Porém ao fazer a requisição no código obtenho o seguinte erro:

A solicitação foi anulada: Não foi possível criar um canal seguro para SSL/TLS.

Os dados do request:

Parametros :

```html
<xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" >
 <consNFeDest versao="2.00 / 3.10" xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe">
   <tpAmb>1</tpAmb>
   <cUF>31</cUF>
   <xServ>CONSULTAR NFE DEST</xServ>
    <CNPJ>000000000</CNPJ>
    <indNFe>0</indNFe>
   <indEmi>1</indEmi>
   <ultNSU>0</ultNSU>
</consNFeDest>
</xml>
```

Servico : https://www.nfe.fazenda.gov.br/NFeConsultaDest/NFeConsultaDest.asmx Versao : 2.00 / 3.10

Codigo:

```
var parametros = Serializar<ConsultaStatusDoServico>();
    var certificado = PegarCertificado(loja);
    var ws = new SefazMG.NfeStatusServico2();
    var cabecalho = new nfeCabecMsg() { cUF = Contexto.ConfiguracoesDaNFE.Estado.ID.ToString(), versaoDados = Contexto.ConfiguracoesDaNFE.VersaoDoServicoDeStatus };
    var xEle = new XmlDocument(); 
    xEle.LoadXml(parametros);
    XmlNode node = xEle.DocumentElement;
    ws.ClientCertificates.Add(certificado);
    ws.Url = "https://www.nfe.fazenda.gov.br/NFeConsultaDest/NFeConsultaDest.asmx";
    ws.nfeCabecMsgValue = cabecalho;
    var nfeDadosMsg = new nfeDadosMsg();
    nfeDadosMsg.Any = new XmlNode[] { xEle.ChildNodes.Item(0) };

    var sb = new StringBuilder();


    nfeDadosMsg.Any = new XmlNode[] { xEle };
    nfeDadosMsg.Any[0] = node;
    try
    {
        var resposta = ws.nfeStatusServicoNF2(nfeDadosMsg);
        sb.AppendLine("Resposta : " + Serializar(resposta));

    }catch(Exception ex)
    {
        sb.AppendLine(ex.Message);
    }
```

Erro:

A solicitação foi anulada: Não foi possível criar um canal seguro para SSL/TLS.

Comment: Ola amigo, resolveu o seu problema?

Comment: Sim havia divergência entre o CNPJ e o Certificado

Comment: onde vc alterou o contenttype ?

Answer (score 4):

Por mais incrível que pareça pelo texto do erro, o causador do problema se deve ao fato que diferente de outros serviços do mesmo provedor, este não aceita o ContentType = "aplication/xml", somente o ContentType = "text/xml".

Muito obrigado pela contribuição de todos.

Answer (score 4):

Olá, passei pelo mesmo problema porém tentando baixar um arquivo de um site rodando em background com a linguagem C#. 
Para fazer o download do arquivo uso o método GetResponse() do Web Client, o sistema funcionava perfeitamente até que um dia passou a dar erro : "A solicitação foi anulada: Não foi possível criar um canal seguro para SSL/TLS"

Tentei de todas formas citadas acima e nada deu certo, até que verifiquei a versão do .net framework utilizado, **4.5.2**. Em seguida troquei para a versão **4.6** , somente desta forma solucionei o problema. Voltando a rodar novamente no servidor windows server 2016 e windows 10

Observação:  É possível que com uma futura atualização do windows a aplicação pare de funcionar.

Espero ter ajudado a todos.

Comment: Eu também estava com o problema e essa foi a única forma de resolvê-lo. Obrigado!

Answer (score 3):

Verifique se há permissão à chave privada do certificado.

- Abra o gerenciador de certificados

  - [tecla windows] + r -> mmc -> Arquivo -> Adicionar Snap-in -> Certificados -> conta do computador
- Selecione o certificado (que normalmente esta na pasta "pessoal"). Na barra à direita do gerenciador de certificados, selecione "mais opções" -> "todas tarefas" -> "gerenciar chaves privadas".

Eu não sei ao certo qual usuário é necessário dar permissão, mas deve ser o IUSR, ou ASP.NET, mas para verificar se é isso que está te causando problema, de permissão à "todos".

## goww

Comment: Somente complementando, o usuário que necessita de permissão é o "IIS_IUSRS"

Answer (score 1):

> A solicitação foi anulada: Não foi possível criar um canal seguro para
>   SSL/TLS.
>   esse erro é bastante genérico e possui diversas coisas que podem o gerar...

já tive um erro parecido só que no meu caso foi por conta de que o servidor não estava aceitando ou melhor validando o certificado HTTPS.. então eu criei isso daqui que resolveu meu problema vê se pode te ajudar...

```
private void AlgumLugar() {
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback 
    += new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(AllwaysGoodCertificate);
}

private static bool AllwaysGoodCertificate(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors policyErrors) {

   return true;
}
```

adicione isso aqui também, pra poder funcionar no windows 7 também !!:

```
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
```

faça um teste e vê se funciona... comigo funcionou !

Comment: No meu caso funcionou, porém precisei além disso mudar a versão do .net framework para 4.6

Answer (score 0):

Adicionei isso e deu certo...

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
```